# syntax error at or near "to_DATE" getting when calling SP PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

This is how I call the SP in PostgreSQL

```
CALL qis_pk_test.qis_pk_testBill(
     to_DATE('03-02-2023','DD-MM-YYYY')::timestamp without time zone, 
    to_DATE('03-02-2023','DD-MM-YYYY')::timestamp without time zone 
);
fetch all in qis_pk_test.qis_pk_testBill;
```

I'm getting following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to_DATE"
LINE 2:      to_DATE('03-02-2023','DD-MM-YYYY'')::timestamp without ...
             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 51
```

I tried this based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574313/postgresql-to-date)

```
CALL qis_pk_test.qis_pk_testBill(
     to_DATE(''03-02-2023'',''DD-MM-YYYY'')::timestamp without time zone, 
    to_DATE(''03-02-2023'',''DD-MM-YYYY'')::timestamp without time zone 
);
fetch all in qis_pk_test.qis_pk_testBill;
```

But it's also not working for me

Comment: What tool are you using to run that? The error message seems to suggest that there are other layers involved in running that code. And why use a stored procedure to return a result. Using a set-returning function is the recommended approach any you wouldn't have to deal with fetching ref cursors.

Comment: Does using `'2023-03-02'::timestamp` work instead of the `to_date()` call?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using pgAdmin 4

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name as a testing purpose I tried SELECT to_date('2014/04/25', 'YYYY/MM/DD'); its worked

Comment: The error shows double quotes, but not the statement.  Make sure you are executing the right statement and returning the right error.

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson updated the error properly